# Mouse takes too long to be discovered

Tags: linux, windows-vista, keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

I have a dual PC setup with a device that allows me to use one mouse, keyboard, and monitor (I don't remember what that's called). One PC is running Vista and the other is running Linux. When I switch from Vista to Linux, I can use the PC almost immediately, but when I go from Linux to Vista, Windows has to go through the process of "discovering" the mouse and keyboard all over again, which takes a while. When I'm switching back and forth frequently, this becomes quite a pain. Is there a way to keep the mouse and keyboard from being "disconnected" from Windows or be discovered faster or something like that?

Comment: "I don't remember what that's called" - A "KVM Switch" - Keyboard, Video, Mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of the hosts are on the same network, I would suggest using the project at http://synergy-project.org/. This program *should* keep the mouse and keyboard connected via software signal.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I hadn't seen that program before. That's probably my best bet.